# Cauchy product application with Euler's number

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$ we have to prove $\sum_{n} \frac{x^n}{n!}\times \sum_{n} \frac{(-x)^n}{n!}=1$.

What I've tried has been using the Cauchy product to multiply series and I've tried to involve the Newton's binomial but I can not get the result because I don`t know how to work with the product of series.

Any help with this proof?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used the right way :

The two series are absolutely convergent, thus the product of the series is the serie of the Cauchy products, whose coefficient is

$$u_n = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{x^k}{k!}\frac{(-x)^{n-k}}{(n-k)!}$$

But, for $n\geq 1$, it can be rewrited as 
$$u_n = \frac{x^n}{n!}\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} (-1)^{n-k}$$
which is equal to 0 by binomial theorem.

Edit : I'll answer your comment.
For $n\geq 1$, $u_n = 0$ because $\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} (-1)^{n-k} = (1-1)^n = 0$.

Then, $$\left( \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!}\right)\left( \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-x)^k}{k!}\right) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty u_k = u_0 = 1$$

Comment: $u_0$ is 1 because the summatory is from k=0 to n=0, right?

Comment: Yes, and $0! = x^0 = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

well if you prove
$E(x) E(y) = E(x+y)$

then it follows if we define $E(x)$ by the power series. (Put $y=-x.$)

To prove this, note that both
$E(x)
$
and $E(x+y)/E(y)$ solve the equation $f'=f$ with $f(0)=1$ so they must agree by uniqueness of solutions of ODEs.